# Structure Navigation Showing Hidden Entries

Tags: templates, structure, navigation

I have what seems like a pretty straightforward Structure navigation menu, but for some reason, the entries that "Hide from Nav?" set to "Yes" are still displaying in the navigation.

[image: Hide from Nav selected in channel entry]

The page is even labelled as "(hidden)" in the Structure interface, but still it shows up in the navigation.

[image: Structure Listing]

Is there something wrong with my code?

```
<div class="nav-menu">
{exp:structure_entries depth="2" current_class="active"}
    {if {count} ==1}<ul id="top-nav" {if {current+child}==1}class="active" {/if}>{/if}
    {if {depth} == 1}
        {!-- Top Level --}
        <li>
            <a href="#">{title}</a>
        {if {children_total} == 0}{!-- No Children - so close markup --}</li>{/if}  
        {if:else}{!-- Children (not top level) --}
            {if {sibling_count} == 1}
                {!-- First child - so open markup --}
                <div class="subnav-dropdown">
                    <ul class="level{depth} subnav">
            {/if}
                        <li>
                            <a href="{page_uri}">{title}</a>
                            {close_markup}
                        {if {total_children} == 0 || {depth} == {restricted_depth}}</li>{/if}
                    {if {last_sibling} && {sibling_count} == {sibling_total}}
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </li>{/if}
        {/close_markup}{/if}
    {if {count}=={total_results}}</ul>{/if}
{/exp:structure_entries}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll hazard a guess here and say that the reason your "Hidden from Nav" entries are being output is because you're not actually using a Structure module tag, but the *Structure Entries plugin.*

I'm not sure what kind of support Structure Entries has for Structure's Hidden from Nav feature. What version are you using? It sounds like there is a beta version that has a `hide_from_nav="yes"` parameter. There is a link to the beta v1.3.4 on its [devotee page.](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/structure-entries)

This Structure Entries [support thread](https://getsatisfaction.com/twobelowzero/topics/hide_from_nav_variable?topic-reply-list%5Bsettings%5D%5Bfilter_by%5D=all&topic-reply-list%5Bsettings%5D%5Breply_id%5D=12663679#reply_12663679) might also help.

A possible alternative would be to switch your template to use the Structure module's [`{exp:structure:nav}`](http://buildwithstructure.com/tags#tag_navigation) tag or another of the Structure module's tags.

Comment: This was the only way I knew of to make the dynamic dropdown navigation work. I tried using the exclude parameter, and that didn't work either.

Comment: What version of the Structure Entries plugin are you using?

Comment: The 1.3.4 beta version solved the problem for me. Thanks, Alex!